# Jumping to a specific logation for DLL injection : OllyDbg

Tags: malware, dynamic-analysis

Hypothetically,  If I'm hijacking a DLL but user space is in a sandbox; upon debugging, sandbox initiates at 0x345678 and I want to move to the space before it initiates:
Can I call a jmp function like "xyz-volatile(jmp 0x1100000);" to jump to the space before the sandbox initiates?

Comment: How does this sandbox work? I am pretty sure its not based on just IP value, rather making some syscalls, dropping privileges or some other feature provided by OS.

Comment: Ofcourse not, for a moment just consider I am working within ollydbg tool with in windows , lets say win 10